# int object is not iterable

Tags: python, lista

Estoy teniendo un problema con un for y me da este error:

```
for i, j in range( len (lst) ):
```

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

No tengo idea de porque pasa. Alguien me podria ayudar?

Comment: Bienvenido Guido Biotti a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: ¿Que es lo que buscas? por que `for i, j in range( len (lst) )` no tiene sentido, `range()` retorna básicamente un conjunto de enteros y no puedes desempaquetar dos variables, en todo caso debiera ser así: `for i in range( len (lst) ):`

Comment: Muchas gracias, no se porque crei que eso era correcto. Ahora ya funciona